# PowerShell Error: "No Runspace Available" in Windows PowerShell, but not in ISE

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, runspace

I have a portion of a larger PowerShell script that processes a CSV file with computer information taken from Intune. The script works as intended when run in the PowerShell ISE, but when executed in Windows PowerShell, it throws the following error after processing about 100 entries:

`*format-default : There is no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread. You can provide one in the DefaultRunspace property of the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace type. The script block you attempted to invoke was:*` 
The csv it is reading data from has the following columns:
"HostID","ComputerName","EmployeeID","Notes","WorkOrder","GroupName","LastLogonUserName","ExternalIP","OSVersion","Serial Number","Model"

It is using Microsoft Graph API to get the OSVersion, Serial Number, and Model. The data for the other columns is taken from our Logmein account. Here is the code snippet:

```
$tenantId = 'string for tenant ID'
$appId = 'string for app ID'
$appSecret = 'string for app secret'

#Get the OAuth token
$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$tokenBody = @{
    client_id     = $appId
    scope         = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    client_secret = $appSecret
    grant_type    = 'client_credentials'
}
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenUrl -Method Post -Body $tokenBody
$token = $tokenResponse.access_token


$secureToken = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $token -AsPlainText -Force
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $secureToken

$csvData = @()

foreach ($host in $report.Hosts) {
    $jsonEntry = $allBatchData | Where-Object { $_.hosts."$($host.HostID)" -ne $null }
    if ($jsonEntry) {
        $csvData += [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Computer Name"     = $host.ComputerName
            "HostID"            = $host.HostID
            "LastLogonUserName" = $jsonEntry.hosts."$($host.HostID)".lastLogonUserName
            "ExternalIP"        = $jsonEntry.hosts."$($host.HostID)".externalIp
            "Operating System"  = $host.OperatingSystem
        }
    }
}


$csvData = Import-Csv "\CentralData.csv"

foreach ($row in $csvData) {
    $cleanComputerName = ($row.ComputerName -split '\s')[0]
    $hostID = $row.HostID
    $hostDataFromJson = $allBatchData.hosts | Where-Object { $_.id -eq $hostID }
    $matchingDevice = Get-MgBetaDeviceManagementManagedDevice -Filter "DeviceName eq '$cleanComputerName'" | Select-Object OsVersion, SerialNumber, Model -First 1
    
   if ($allBatchData.hosts.$hostID) {
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LastLogonUserName" -Value $allBatchData.hosts.$hostID.lastLogonUserName -Force
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ExternalIP" -Value $allBatchData.hosts.$hostID.externalIp -Force
    }

    if ($matchingDevice) {
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OSVersion" -Value $matchingDevice.OsVersion -Force
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Serial Number" -Value $matchingDevice.SerialNumber -Force
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Model" -Value $matchingDevice.Model -Force
        Write-Output "Fetched OSVersion and Serial Number for ${cleanComputerName}: $($matchingDevice.OsVersion) and $($matchingDevice.SerialNumber) and $($matchingDevice.Model)"
    } else {
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OSVersion" -Value "N/A" -Force
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Serial Number" -Value "N/A" -Force
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Model" -Value "N/A" -Force
        Write-Output "No OSVersion or Serial Number found for ${cleanComputerName}"
    }
    $csvData | Export-Csv "path to CentralData.csv" -NoTypeInformation

}

$csvData | Export-Csv "path to CentralData.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Thank you for your time.

**Attempted Solutions:**

- I've tried understanding the concept of runspaces in PowerShell, but I'm still unclear why this issue arises only in Windows PowerShell and not in the ISE.
- The script successfully processes approximately 100 computers before failing, which suggests a potential resource or threading issue. I've tried finding issues similar to this found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2024), but this has quickly gone outside of my expertise.

**Questions:**

1. What does the error message about the lack of a runspace in the thread imply in the context of my script?
2. Why might this script work in PowerShell ISE but fail in Windows PowerShell?